# How to make a 2-d linear function using a third variable for the iterator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, graphing-functions, parametrization, slope

Say, for example, you have the vector $\vec {PQ} = \langle8,4\rangle$. As we all learned in Algebra I, the "traditional" slope (y-units per x-unit) would be $\frac{4}{8}$, and the slope for x-units per y-unit would be $\frac{8}{4}$.

This begs the question: Since we can find the x and y slopes, would it be possible to have a third variable (let's call it "z") for the iterator?

What I am trying to get at is this:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lc}
z & \text{x} & \text{y} \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 4 & 2 \\
3 & 6 & 3 \\
4 & 8 & 4
\end{array}
$$

Since I am dealing with a vector, how would I find the end size of `z`? For example, how would I go about determining that the end size of `z` in my example vector is 4, if I didn't know it before hand?

Comment: In this example $z$ is just $x/y$, which is constant. So you know it whenever you know one point on the line.

Comment: Are you referring to a parametrization of the vector? This can be done by saying $y(t)=t$ and $x(t)=2t$ for a vector defined as $<2t,t>$. In this sense, you could get an accurate value of $t$ from any given value for $x$ or $y$.

Comment: @EthanBolker As I said in my edit, I know that - I am trying to determine a formula to find $\text{z}$ when it isn't obvious like here.

Comment: @StephenGoree Would you mind putting that in an answer? I need to check it, but I believe that's what I am looking for.

Comment: @TheDaleks Sorry for the delay. I've posted it a little more in-depth as an answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you're referring to the parametrization of a curve (a line, in your case, but a curve more generally). Here's how it works:

We have a line, and in this case, it can be described by $y=\frac{1}{2}x$ or, possibly a bit easier for this circumstance, $2y=x$. Now, we come up with two functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ which describe the values of $x$ and $y$ for any value of a third variable $t$. Because of the way you've set this up, I'm going to say $y(t)=t$. Now, we can find the second function by noting that $x(t)=2y(t)=2t$.

At this point, we have enough to say that the line $2y=x$ is *parametrized* by the functions $x(t)=2t$ and $y(t)=t$, which we refer to as *parametric equations*. If you put these two functions into a vector as $\langle x(t),y(t)\rangle=\langle 2t,t\rangle$, it describes *all* vectors of this form, not just those you've listed in the table. However, if you'd like to iterate the vectors you're describing as a sequence, you can do so with the set $\{\langle 2t,t\rangle|t\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

As for your question about how to find the value of the iterator based on the vector, this actually tells you quite nicely, because we've already said that $t=y$.

If you want a little more info about this sort of thing, I'd look up a bit more about parametrization, if you haven't already. I believe MathByFives on YouTube has a few videos about parametrization, if you'd like something informative, but also silly and whimsical.